# mxGraph shows grid, but does not show images

Tags: javascript, java, mxgraph

I'm using the [mxGraph](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/manual.html) to develop a drawable area in a web page.

This is a legacy code and I'm trying to understand it, because the area is not showing any images besides a grid.

Here is my javascript code to show a simple diagram

```
//define a window to show the image and put a grid as background
container.style.background = 'url("js/src/images/grid.gif")';
//some other definitions here

var model = new mxGraphModel();
var graph = new mxGraph(container, model);

var id = _GET("id");
mxUtils.post("../Diagram", 
"action=get&id="+id, 
function(req)
{
    var node = req.getDocumentElement();
    var dec = new mxCodec(node.ownerDocument);
    dec.decode(node, graph.getModel());
}, 
function(error){
    console.log("Error in the design area");
    console.log(error);
});
```

The `../Diagram` is a servlet Java that you can see below:

```
try {
    BufferedReader buffRead = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/home/glassfish/mySite/Repository/"+getId()+"/"+getName()+".txt")); 
    String line = ""; 
    while (true) { 
        if (line != null) { 
            file = line; 
        } else {
            break; 
        }
        line = buffRead.readLine(); 
    } 
    buffRead.close();
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("File not found");
}
return file;
```

The returned XML (file) is like below:

```
<root>
    <mxCell id="0"/>
    <mxCell id="1" parent="0"/>
    <mxCell id="2" parent="1" style="shape=ellipse;fillColor=#33CCFF" value="Objective" vertex="1">
        <mxGeometry as="geometry" height="40" width="100" x="262" y="90"/>
    </mxCell>
</root>
```

However, the result in the screen is always the grid only

[image: grid]

When I debug the line `dec.decode(node, graph.getModel());` to see the `node` value I got a XML Object that contains the info returned by Java.

In Chrome I don't receive any message in the console, but when I test it in Firefox I receive an warning saying that I have a "XML parsing error in the file graph.properties", but this file is not a XML (actually, I don't know what is this file). I'm also pasting the file here

graph.properties

```
alreadyConnected=Nodes already connected
containsValidationErrors=Contains validation errors
updatingDocument=Updating Document. Please wait...
updatingSelection=Updating Selection. Please wait...
collapse-expand=Collapse/Expand
doubleClickOrientation=Doubleclick to change orientation
close=Close
error=Error
done=Done
cancel=Cancel
ok=OK
```

*UPDATE*

I still have not solved the problem, but I got a new evidence.

When I debug the `dec.decode(node, graph.getModel());` line, I have two properties for the `dec` variable. A XMLDocument and also a empty array. I think that the problem could be in the encoding part, but I not found any tip in the [page about mxCodec](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/js-api/files/io/mxCodec-js.html).

[image: image of debug]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution to the problem.

The error was in the Javascript part, but I don't know why the console did not show any problem. Anyway, replace the original success function for the code below solves the problem.

```
    function(req)
    {
        var doc = req.getDocumentElement();
        var codec = new mxCodec(doc);
        var elt = doc.firstChild;
        var cells = [];

        while (elt != null)
        {
          cells.push(codec.decode(elt));
          elt = elt.nextSibling;
        }

        graph.addCells(cells);
    }
```